# Bit fields maked more optimized

Tags: c, packing, bit-packing, structure-packing

I'm making some code for a 16 bits microprocessor. My memory is quite limited at 128 KB. IAR C/C++ Compiler for MSP430
I need to implement some code to save some memory.

I tried to implemented this with this C characteristic implementation.

```
struct {
    unsigned int widthValidated : 1;
    unsigned int heightValidated : 1;
} status;
```

But with this bit of code I still only use 1 bit of a 16 bit word.

My goal is to use the same word sized bit of memory for two 8 bit variables. The first variable should be 8 bits left of the second variable.

```
struct {
   unsigned int widthValidated : 8; //8 bits for this
   unsigned int heightValidated : 8; // 8 left over for this
} status;
```

Is this possible? Are there any implementations of this or is there a library in C for this? How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Use a `char` instead of a bitfield.

Comment: You can use `char`, but what's the problem with the code there?

Comment: Bitfields is the part of C language that I really dislike: they are hard to use and port across different implementations. I stick to characters or bitmasks.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to convert the bitfield to the new type? Do you want to implement something using the 8-bit fields instead of 1-bit fields? Do you want to match the bit positions with some specific requirement? What is the problem you want to solve?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I'd say that bitfields are **impossible** to port across different implementations.

Comment: Or you could just use unsigned shorts if you really want bitfields

Comment: For _portable_ bit fields, use `unsigned` (not `unsigned shorts`), and give up precise control of endian, size.  Do not populate with `fread()`.

Comment: Restate "goal is use the same space of memory for the two variables 8 bits reserved for the first variable and 8 bits left over for the second varible." to add clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use bit-fields for any purpose, particularly not for memory mapping, since they are very poorly standardized.

What you should do is to use the `stdint.h` types. Declare two `uint8_t` variables. You save memory in microcontrollers by carefully picking the necessary type whenever declaring a variable.

For example, in professional programs for limited microcontrollers, a typical for loop is written as `for(uint8_t i=0; ...` and not with "sloppy typing" `for(int i=0; ...`.

The trick is: whenever you declare *any* variable, then *always* consider what is the maximum value that variable might get. By doing so, you save memory and prevent overflow bugs.

Comment: I disagree. It makes code easier to read. It is not portable but porability is not main uC programmers target.

Comment: @P__J__ Even if you don't write code which is portable between different MCUs often (I do), you _will_ eventually port code between compilers for the same MCU. Also, bit-fields make code impossible to read. Given `struct { int MSB:1 }`, we have potentially created code where the LSB is named MSB - we don't know. How exactly is that readable?

Comment: **you will eventually port code between compilers for the same MCU** I use IAR, Keil, gcc & Green Hills compilers at work and bitfields are 100% percent portable between them.  I think your opinion is not backed by the real life experience, only based on the C standard. PS At the moment we use only ARM Cortex-Mx micros. But we were using PIC years ago (MCC18 compiler and this one was not supporting > 32 bits bitfields)

Comment: @P__J__ Go ahead and read the actual compiler docs for each compiler and you'll find that they aren't.

Comment: start using them and then comment

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save memory just use smaller types when you declare the struct

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t flag1: 1;
    uint8_t flag2: 1;
    uint8_t flag3: 1;
    uint8_t flag4: 1;
    uint8_t flag5: 1;
}myflags;

uint8_t foo(myflags f)
{
    return f.flag4;
}

uint8_t foo1(uint8_t flags)
{
    return !!(flags & (1 << 3));
}

void foo3()
{
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(myflags));
}
```

it makes code easier to read debug and modify.

```
foo:
        ubfx    r0, r0, #3, #1
        bx      lr
foo1:
        ubfx    r0, r0, #3, #1
        bx      lr
foo3:
        movs    r1, #1
        ldr     r0, .L5
        b       printf
.L5:
        .word   .LC0
.LC0:
        .ascii  "%zu\012\000"
```

Many uCs have special instructions to extract bitfields move them to the lower bits and signed and unsigned extend the result to the register/variable size

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us what specific platform you are using so I can't give you a detailed enough answer but what you want is to remove the padding from your struct. Or in other words you want to [pack your structs.](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/)

This is how I understand you to want your memory layout to be two bytes in one 16 bit word.

```
struct {
    uint8_t widthValidated;
    uint8_t heightValidated;
} status;
```

[To require the compiler](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/#_overriding_alignment_rules) to create a certain boundary you can do:

for arm:

```
struct __attribute__((packed)){
    uint8_t widthValidated;
    uint8_t heightValidated;
} status;
```

for gcc:

```
#pragma pack (1)
struct __attribute__((packed)){
    uint8_t widthValidated;
    uint8_t heightValidated;
} status;
```

Your platform may differ but it should come up how to do this when you search for struct packing.

A union inside the struct would also be an option but this wouldn't necessarily be portable as bit/byte ordering may differ from platform to platform.

You see me using `uint8_t` above . This is a `typedef` done inside `<stdint.h>`. This is a standardized way to declare an integer variable with a defined width. Useful types inside a microcontroller are the undefined integer family of: `uint8_t` (8-bits), `uint16_t` (16-bits) and `uint32_t` (32-bits). And their signed counterparts: `int8_t` (8-bits), `int16_t` (16-bits) and `int32_t` (32-bits).